# Media query iOS retina seems not responding

Tags: html, ios, css, mobile, media-queries

Just tried my hand at using media queries to make my site responsive.
I have a div that, on a normal size desktop browser is 50% of the total width of the viewport. When using mobile iOS, I want that to change to 100% of the width. That works currently with the following HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0" />
<link href='style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="smalldevice.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="social">Content</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The regarding CSS for the normal page is:

```
#social {
position:relative;
margin-top:50px;
left:0;
right:0;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
text-align:center;
width: 100%;
max-width:640px;
}
```

And the smalldevice.css is:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 640px) {

#social {
width:50%;
}
```

When resizing my browser window that works when I reach a viewport width of 640px, and it changes the width of #social to 100%. Testing on iOS mobile works too. But when changing to landscape mode (viewport width becomes 1136px, thus using the media query, it does not change the width of the #social element to 50%. On a desktop with a resizable window it does work. What's going wrong?

Edit: I set up a demo that seems to work when resizing the browser (I added a background-color so the div-width is visible) here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/AtysL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@media screen and (min-width: 640px), (orientation: landscape)
```

Should work just fine.

Comment: Unfortunately, when you use the site on eg a computer it will not change to 50% since that requires landscape orientation. Or should I switch to max-width then and have the mobile version contained in that? Edit, I made a mistake: it does change to 50%. Thanks, this solved my problem!